# Change is_superuser field in Django

Tags: python, django

I have a table with so called "Reviewers", which are normal Django `auth_users`, and they are either superuser or not. This is declared in the `is_superuser` field (from [django.contrib.auth](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/) )

I wrote this function to change the superuser status of every reviewer that was selected with a checkbox:

```
def change_su(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        ids = request.POST.getlist('selected')

        for id in ids:
            try:
                rev = Reviewer.objects.get(pk=id)
                if rev.is_superuser == 1:
                    rev.is_superuser = 0
                    messages.info(request, _('User with id %(id)s is no superuser anymore') % {'id': id})
                else:
                    rev.is_superuser = 1
                    messages.info(request, _('User with id %(id)s is now superuser') % {'id': id})

            except Exception as e:
                logging.getLogger(__name__).exception(e)
                messages.error(request, _('Failed to change superuser status for reviewer with id %(id)s') % {'id': id})

 return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('admin_index'))
```

If I select a user and click on the button that calls this function, it says "User with id .. is no superuser anymore" or "User with id .. is now superuser", so the function recognizes the `is_superuser` field and can read what's in it. However, the superuser status remains unchanged.

Is this somehow a special field that I have no permission to change?

**Edit:** Here is the corrected code which works. Thank you Daniel!

```
def change_su(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        ids = request.POST.getlist('selected')

        for id in ids:
            try:
                rev = Reviewer.objects.get(pk=id)
                if rev.is_superuser == 1:
                    rev.is_superuser = 0
                    rev.save()
                    messages.info(request, _('User with id %(id)s is no superuser anymore') % {'id': id})
                else:
                    rev.is_superuser = 1
                    rev.save()
                    messages.info(request, _('User with id %(id)s is now superuser') % {'id': id})

            except Exception as e:
                logging.getLogger(__name__).exception(e)
                messages.error(request, _('Failed to change superuser status for reviewer with id %(id)s') % {'id': id})

 return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('admin_index'))
```

Comment: can you also show Reviewer model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't appear to be calling `rev.save()` anywhere, so changes will not be persisted to the database.

Comment: Oh dear, how stupid I was. I should have seen that myself. Thank you!